# jquery appending images then put them in carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hello i have a button that triggers on click a modal and adding some images to content that should work as a carousel. I dont know how to exactly explain so i'll give you a link to my problem. My script is not working as it should because it triggers the modal, is appending the images but first it triggers the modal so it doesnt display the images in the carousel. if i close the modal and then press the button again the images are there.
here is the [LINK WITH PROBLEM](http://rezerv.city/index.php)

Press on restaurants then on gallery to see the problem. Press gallery twice.
script appending the images

```
<script>
$(\'body\').on(\'click\',\'.gal\',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   var href = $(this).attr(\'href\');
    $.getJSON(href, function(data) {

   $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    $(\'.hidden\').append(\' <div class="item" id="image-1"> <img class="gal img-responsive" title="Image 11" src="http://rezerv.city/clienti/carulcuflori/imagini/galerie/\' +val.poze + \'"></div> \');
});
     });
});
      </script>
```

script for modal and carousel, both are trigger by the same button

```
<script>
       /* activate the carousel */
$("#modal-carousel").carousel({interval:false});

/* change modal title when slide changes */
$("#modal-carousel").on("slid.bs.carousel", function () {
  $(".modal-title").html($(this).find(".active img").attr("title"));
})

/* when clicking a thumbnail */
$(document).on("click", ".galz .gal", function() {

    var content = $(".carousel-inner");
    var title = $(".modal-title");

    content.empty();
    title.empty();

    var id = this.id;
    var repo = $("#img-repo .item");
    var repoCopy = repo.filter("#" + id).clone();
    var active = repoCopy.first();

    active.addClass("active");
    title.html(active.find("img").attr("title"));
    content.append(repoCopy);

    // show the modal
    $("#modal-gallery").modal("show");

 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/u5sok220/2/

you must add class active to first item

```
<div class="item active"><img class="gal img-responsive" ... </div>
<div class="item"><img class="gal img-responsive" ... </div>
<div class="item"><img class="gal img-responsive" ... </div>
...
```

Comment: i tryed your jsfiddle, and i think that's the correct answer but i don't know how to make it working with my external appended data from a link, when i press the button i append images from a link with json data

Comment: i get  invalid assignment left-hand side on true = false

Comment: my typo: first = false; . And do not forget var href = $(this).attr('href');

Comment: script is working now, but should i change that class where i'm appending to .carousel-inner?

Comment: If you want you can do it. I'm in my JSFIDDLE, remove the div .hidden

Comment: you need to insert check whether the images have already been added. because each time you press the button again .gal will add the same image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66109/discussion-between-user3058067-and-dm4web).

Answer (score 0):

What might be happening is a race condition between the $(document).on event and the $("body") event.
This results in the .hidden div in the popup not yet being populated when the getJSON callback completes.

I would suggest changing your code as follows, to prevent this 'race condition':

```
<script>
$('body').on('click','.gal, .galz .gal',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $.getJSON(href, function(data) {

       renderPopup();
       $.each(data, function(key, val) {
         $(\'.hidden\').append(' <div class="item" id="image-1"> <img class="gal img-responsive" title="Image 11" src="http://rezerv.city/clienti/carulcuflori/imagini/galerie/' +val.poze + '"></div> ');
});
     });
});
</script>
```

And your second script becomes:

```
<script>
       /* activate the carousel */
$("#modal-carousel").carousel({interval:false});

/* change modal title when slide changes */
$("#modal-carousel").on("slid.bs.carousel", function () {
  $(".modal-title").html($(this).find(".active img").attr("title"));
})

/* when clicking a thumbnail */
var renderPopup = function() {

    var content = $(".carousel-inner");
    var title = $(".modal-title");

    content.empty();
    title.empty();

    var id = this.id;
    var repo = $("#img-repo .item");
    var repoCopy = repo.filter("#" + id).clone();
    var active = repoCopy.first();

    active.addClass("active");
    title.html(active.find("img").attr("title"));
    content.append(repoCopy);

    // show the modal
    $("#modal-gallery").modal("show");

 };
 </script>
```

Alternatively, you could probably also just append this to the original code, which will also populate the dialog before the JSON request is ready:

```
// show the modal
$(function(){
    $("#modal-gallery").modal("hide");
});
```

Comment: not working, now it doesnt show the pics at all. That's true, it triggers my modal and carousel after dialog is populated, but that didn't fix:(

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the modal is appearing before the gallery is ready, try this.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(\'body\').on(\'click\',\'.gal\',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr(\'href\');
        $.getJSON(href, function(data) {

            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                $(\'.hidden\').append(\' <div class="item" id="image-1"> 
                <img class="gal img-responsive" title="Image 11"
                src="http://rezerv.city/clienti/carulcuflori/imagini/galerie/\' +val.poze + \'"></div>
                \');
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```